# Is it possible to get access token using Java. I have an integration tool, which needs to get this access token dynamically using Java.

Tags: java, facebook

Is it possible to get access token using Java. I have an integration tool, which needs to get this access token dynamically using Java. Please let me know where should i start from?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540165/session-key-access-token-in-facebook-api

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by dynamically here?? you can easily get access_token using java and have few option either to write complete code or use any well establish API to interact with the Facebook and get `verification_code` and `access_token` for you.I will suggest you not to write complete code yourself and use some third party API

- [scribe-java](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/)

use scribe-java its very light weight and easy to use.

Comment: i want to re-generate expired access token using java. Is this possible?

Comment: for expired access_token you need to start the process again.

Comment: Thanks Umesh for the reply, without using the API can you tell us the way to get the access token after it expires.

Comment: @SravanthiMukkera: you need to redirect user to FB to get new access token as i told you, you can develop your own code base to interact with FB to get access_token.API is only there to cut down your work.

Comment: Hi Umesh, we dont use java script and our application is not a webapplication. We have an facebook app, this app has to be accessed by our integration server. We have a http post and get methods.and we can write Java code arround this. Can you please suggest some link or some example where we can understand how to proceed. We tried using some url provided in facebook documention. But we have been unsuccessful.